# Getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " while loading JSON using (jQuery) $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Code:

```
var json = $.getJSON("http://leezhifei.com/projects/example.json" + "?callback=?", function(data)
{
    console.log("success");
});
```

Json content (or you can just follow the link above):

```
{
    "level" : "0"
}
```

It's been bugging for quite a few days now. I've tried every solution there is (maybe not all), and most of them either gave me the same "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " error, or "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin" for not loading it as "jsonp" ("?callback=?")~!

I'm really running out of ideas here~ ><

Comment: It's not valid JSONP, and it's not on the same domain

Comment: I tried your code... response is coming in network tab...but you are getting the error...try $.ajax instead..